# Connect Solr remotely with django

Tags: python-2.7

I have solr server which run on specific ip and also run python code on another server using django framework and connect django code with mariadb database which access remotely.

I want to access solr in my code remotely.

Please give the solution.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have run the solr on centos 7 on specific ip. and now want to access solr from other server.